# pm2 autostart discord.js bot won't connect again on reboot (raspberry pi)

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, discord.js, pm2

I am hosting a discord.js bot on my raspberry pi 4.
It connects flawlessly when I do it manually with `pm2 start index.js`
Now the issue is when I tried to add it to autostart

```
pm2 autostart
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u pi --hp /home/pi
pm2 save
```

Now when I restart I the process has started up, I get this when I type `pm2 list`
[image]

but the bot will be offline on discord.

In the error logs I have this error repeating multiple times:

```
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN discordapp.com discordapp.com:443
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
```

However if I restart with `pm2 restart 0` the discord bot will be online again.

Comment: It seems like the internet connection is not yet established when the bot starts. When you open `raspi-config`, go to `Boot Options` and check `Wait for Network at Boot`, what is the current value? What happens when you turn it on and reboot? If that doesn't work you might need to add a sleep/delay before connecting to discord

Comment: it worked! thank you so much. Could you post it as an Answer so I can set it as the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the internet connection is not yet established when the bot starts. When you open `raspi-config`, go to `Boot Options` and check `Wait for Network at Boot`, the value should be "yes".

That way, the processes will be started when an internet connection is established.

In newer versions of `raspi-config` this option can be found in `System Options`, then `Network at Boot`.